# Сравнение двух полей в request

Tags: laravel

Мне приходят в `request` два поля (`password`, `confirm_password`).

Могу ли я как-то проверить соответствие двух полей в правилах?
То есть мне нужно, чтобы значения двух полей были одинаковыми или нужно делать своё решение?

Answer (score 1):

По дефолту пароль в Laravel проверяется так:

```
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
```

Правило confirmed говорит о том, что поля password и password_confirmation должны быть одинаковы.

Вы используете поле confirm_password. Наверное стоит изменить имя поля для подтверждения пароля.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас попробую и отпишу)